# Bootstrap: Multiple nested rows within row?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I know you can nest rows within nested columns, but is it 'against the rules' to nest rows directly within rows?

eg:

```
<div class="row">

  <div class="row">
     cols in here
  </div>

  <div class="row">
     cols in here
  </div>

  <div class="row">
     cols in here
  </div>

</div>
```

Or must these always be within columns?

Comment: Per [bootstrap guidelines, third point under introduction](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) - *"..and only columns may be immediate children of rows"*. This is because of the padding which Bootstrap uses for its layout, it is a good practice to nest via `row-column-row` pattern.

Comment: @Abhitalks ah cool. Want to make that an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> is it 'against the rules' to nest rows directly within rows?

Not *against the rules* as such, but not a best practice as per the guidelines.

Per [bootstrap guidelines, third point under introduction](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) -

> ..and only columns may be immediate children of rows".

*<sub>Edit: [This is still true with Bootstrap 4.0 Beta](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/). The link to the docs above will automatically redirect to the version 3.3 documentation. Thank you [@Aakash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5284695/aakash-martand) for pointing this out.</sub>

This is because of the padding which Bootstrap uses for its layout, it is a good practice to nest via `row-column-row` pattern i.e. nest a row with one column across to nest.

See the difference in the snippet below. The first set of markup breaks the Bootstrap layout, although nothing bad happens.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">One</div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">Two</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">One</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">Two</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">One</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12">Two</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12">Three</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Abitalks. Would you know anyway to achieve something like my above example?

Comment: One simple way would be (without nesting) - instead of the inner rows, just mark them up as columns with 12 col width (`col-xs-12`). They will then automatically become rows.

Comment: ah, so you can have multiple columns that exceed 12 long? That's by the book?

Comment: @MeltingDog: There. added into the answer code, a third markup set which is your use-case.

Comment: This is old, I know, but as this shows up in response to a specific question, see bootstrap 4 documentation where a row is a direct child of a column:
[https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#nesting](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#nesting)

Comment: @Rogelio Yes. Row can be direct child of column. This is true for BS 5 as well. Where’s the problem? I don’t think there is anything to the contrary in this answer.

Comment: There was a comment that had stated something along the lines of "NO THAT ISN'T THE CASE" which I had flagged and is since removed, my comment makes more sense in that context.