# Multiple rows inside a row with Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create a full width page using Bootstrap. I have a setup similar to this:

```
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            The first row goes here
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            The second row goes here
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            The third row goes here
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

If I wanted to create a row inside a row, how would I do that? This is what I am trying to achieve:

```
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="row text-center">
                <h1>Some title</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    Grid perhaps
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    More grid
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

So basically I want to put the title on one row and some grids on another row. The tricky part here is, I want to place some columns that are 4 columns wide in the middle, and then have "2 columns padding" on the left and right.

[image]

My question may sound like others, but is unique because of the padding. How do I make this layout properly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap: Multiple nested rows within row?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32433124/bootstrap-multiple-nested-rows-within-row)

Comment: @Mattonit Doesn't work with how I'm doing this.

Comment: So what's wrong with the code that you currently have?

Comment: Why are you trying to nest rows? Surely you really just have two rows, one after the other.

Comment: You can use the `offset-md-2` class.

Comment: @Quentin I'm doing a full width layout page. It would make sense that each row is 100% wide. If I wanted each row to have two rows in them, how would I do that? That's my question.

Comment: @MortenMoulder — "It would make sense that each row is 100% wide" — Yes. That's rather the point of a row.

Comment: @LuudvanKeulen What's wrong? You tell me: https://jsfiddle.net/L1uq1mxn/

Comment: @MortenMoulder — "If I wanted each row to have two rows in them, how would I do that?" — Why do you want that? It doesn't make sense to do that.

Comment: @Quentin Then surely you can see what I mean and what's wrong.

Comment: @MortenMoulder — No! I can't see what you mean. As I said, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Quentin Two rows after each other doesn't make sense? Then what does make sense? How would you make a title and perhaps a few rows beneath it with information? col-*-12? Yeah, that's basically a row.

Comment: @MortenMoulder — Rows after each other makes sense. `<row></row><row></row><row></row>`. Rows *inside* each other does not. `<row><row></row><row></row></row>`

Comment: @Quentin http://i.imgur.com/IGwQqoh.png - If that's not how you're supposed to do it, please enlighten me.

Comment: @MortenMoulder — That's sequential rows, not nested rows.

Comment: @Quentin Assuming there are 10 like my screenshot underneath each other, would you consider it a row or a container? Stack 10 of my screenshots on top of each other. If that's not a row, I should quit this.

Comment: It isn't a row. It's a *collection* of rows. There's no Bootstrap specific class for a collection of rows. Possibly you use a plain div. Possibly a section. Possibly you don't bother adding any extra markup at all: There's not much point unless you plan to style it or access it with JS.

Comment: This discussion was actually helpful... I was attempting to do the same thing - but for different reasons. I was implementing nested rows as I was collapsing a sub-set of them. Initially the content of the `collapse` row was a single line - but then it became multi-line, hence rows within rows.... but a plain old `<div />` to hold the collapse class was all I actually needed. `<div class="row">...</div><div class="collapse"><div class="row">...</div><div class="row">...</div></div><div class="row">...</div>`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Bootstrap has a smart (but delicate) gutters system providing "natural"  (`margin`s + `padding`s) for content on all devices <sup>**1**</sup>.

This system is based on two simple assumptions:

- columns are immediate children of `.row`s <sup>**2**</sup>
- content is placed inside columns

That's why, if you want to place a `.row` inside another `.row` (to further divide one of your cols), you'd have to use this markup:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-2">
           Grid perhaps
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
           More grid
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The above doesn't make much sense by itself (you could just use the markup of the child row and you'd get the same result). But it's useful when you want to offset (or limit) an entire area of a layout, like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2 col-sm-10 offset-sm-1 col offset-0">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">Grid</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">More grid</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">Grid</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">More grid</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">Grid</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">More grid</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">Grid</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">More grid</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">Grid</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">More grid</div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/rqLkynyn/) for a live example.

---

<sup>**1**</sup> To get rid of Bootstrap's gutters (in v4),  one would need to apply `no-gutters` class on `.row`.

<sup>**2**</sup> This is a *"general principle"*, not a *"strict rule"*. Other elements are allowed (and even recommended) as direct children of `.row`s (such as [column breaks](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#column-breaks)). At the other end, other elements extend from `.row`s (such as `.form-row`s), thus inheriting the gutters system and being valid column parents.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/L1uq1mxn/2/ - That does not give me the wanted result.

Comment: Of course it doesn't. You forgot to mention you're using Bootstra 4, which is still in `alpha`! [`Try this`](https://jsfiddle.net/L1uq1mxn/4/)

Comment: It literally says Bootstrap 4 in the title and in the tag... It's mentioned twice.

Comment: Ok, my bad. I missed that bit. Updated my answer.

Comment: So what's the deal with this? It adds some padding to the first column, then the second column is put right after it and then there's 2 columns left at the back with nothing in it?

Comment: @MortenMoulder Generally speaking having empty containers just for alignment is considered bad practice. It was OK-ish 20 years ago, though.

Comment: That's true and I agree with that. Let's imagine there are n amount of columns, and I want the first ones of each row to have an offset of 2 and the last one to have an offset of 2 to the right, how would I do something like that the best possible way? Would I have to check if `index % 4 == 0` and then add some stuff or is there a smart way Bootstrap can help me?

Comment: @MortenMoulder Inside a `row` you create one single column: `col-8 offset-2`. In it you put a `row`. In that `row` you put as many `col-6`s as you like. There's no point in adding the padding to children, based on complicated responsive calculations, instead of adding it to one single container.

Comment: I suppose that's a good way to do it yeah! Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: @MortenMoulder Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/L1uq1mxn/5/ You're welcome. Happy coding! :: }<(((*> ::)

Answer (score 7):

- `.row` should not be the *immediate* child of another `.row`
- `.col*` should not be the *immediate* child of another `.col*`

From the Bootstrap docs:

> "Content should be placed within columns, and only columns may be
>   immediate children of rows."

I don't understand why you think you need a row in a row, and what's wrong with just using your layout w/o the nested `row`. Do you realize that `col-12` is the width of a full row?

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 text-center">
            <h1>Some title</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            Grid perhaps
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            More grid
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/jfrWn4QDf1

Bootstrap 4, the same rule applies:

> "Rows are wrappers for columns. Each column has horizontal padding
>   (called a gutter) for controlling the space between them... In a grid
>   layout, content must be placed within columns and only columns may be
>   immediate children of rows" __ [Bootstrap 4.1 Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#how-it-works)

---

Linked: [Columns must be immediate children of rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56145259/columns-must-be-immediate-children-of-rows/56147172#56147172)

Comment: the citation "Content should be placed within columns, and only columns may be immediate children of rows." 
 it's for bootstrap 3 not 4
can you please make a confirmation if i'm wrong or right :)

Comment: It's the same in both versions

Comment: Your codeply helped me with a problem at work, thanks!