# Columns must be immediate children of rows?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drupal, bootstrap-4, drupal-8

Columns must be immediate children of rows or I can have other divs inside a row without being a column? I'm working with drupal and it produces a lot of divs inside a container or row I've created.

For example I'm restricted to follow this structure always:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      One of three columns
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or I can do something like this:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="something">
      Something
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="something__else">
      Something else
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it is css, `row` and `col` are classes, you **can** use them freely; but in order to write maintanable, clear code (which others in your team can support), you should follow the framework...

Answer (score 2):

From the [Bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/#how-it-works)...

> "Rows are wrappers for columns. Each column has horizontal padding
> (called a gutter) for controlling the space between them. This padding
> is then counteracted on the rows with negative margins. This way, all
> **the content in your columns is visually aligned down the left side**...
> In a grid layout, content must be placed within columns and only
> columns may be immediate children of rows."

Therefore, the **columns have padding that is specifically designed to work inside the row**. If you use other than col, the content will not be aligned correctly on the left (and right) side as you can see with this example using borders...

https://codeply.com/go/hDcyKs2cWy

Comment: I know how to use the classes when I write HTML by myself. I was asking what should I do in the scenario which I use a CMS like drupal. It's creates various div in which I don't have immediate access so I can't give the classes with the right sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Something that helps me often is to define a border on the  elements. So I can easily test if my Css works the way I want. Like Akber said, row and col are classes so you can use them when you want. But check out this link : [Bootstrap grid documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/) , this way you use the framework as it should.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The reason we follow the framework is to write code that is clearly readable by colleagues, and by yourself when you inevitably come back to the code in 6 months. Writing code with inconsistent classes and structures will work, but it will be unreadable by others.

tl;dr - yes it's fine, but you shouldn't do it.